# Hyperlinks (with autoref) color in beamer

Tags: beamer, hyperref

Consider the following MWE

```
\documentclass[leqno]{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,allcolors=blue}
\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{theorem}
  \label{thm:a_theorem}
    \begin{equation}
      \label{eq:an_equation}
      2 + 2 = 4
    \end{equation}
  \end{theorem}

Equation \ref{eq:an_equation} belongs to \ref{thm:a_theorem}.\\
Equation \eqref{eq:an_equation} belongs to \ref{thm:a_theorem}.\\
Equation \autoref{eq:an_equation} belongs to \autoref{thm:a_theorem}.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I want i) the parentheses around equation number to be part of the hyperlink (and hence also be highlighted in blue) and ii) get `\autoref` to work (and hence obtain `Equation (1) belongs to Theorem (1)` with `(1)` in `Theorem (1)` also highlighted in blue).

[image]

**Edit:** Consider the following MWE which incorporates the suggested solution in the unique answer to this question:

```
\documentclass[leqno]{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,allcolors=blue}
\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  Foo
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
  \phantomsection
  \begin{theorem}
  \label{thm:a_theorem}
  Bar
  \end{theorem}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
  \phantomsection
  \begin{equation}
    \label{eq:an_equation}
    2 + 2 = 4
  \end{equation}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
  \hyperref[eq:an_equation]{Equation (\ref*{eq:an_equation})} belongs
  to \hyperref[thm:a_theorem]{Theorem \ref*{thm:a_theorem}}.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The hyperlinks always point to the first frame and not to the corresponding equation or theorem.

Comment: `beamer` loads `hyperref` with option `implicit=false`. That means that the loading of `hyperref` is stopped earlier and important parts are not loaded. Thus the equations do not even generate anchors. Without `anchor` no link (at least not to the place, where it should go), without anchor name no `\autoref`.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek thanks for the reply and explanation. So is there a workaround that achieves the behavior mentioned in the question?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Class `beamer` loads `hyperref` with option `implicit=false`. That means that the loading of `hyperref` is stopped earlier and important parts are not loaded. Thus the equations do not even generate anchors. Without anchor no link (at least not to the place, where it should go), without anchor name no `\autoref`.

The workaround consists of two parts:

- Anchors are set with `\phantomsection`. The anchor names does not matter anyway,
  because `\autoref` is just a stub for `\ref` with the `beamer` settings.
  However, also `\phantomsection` is a dummy, an empty macro, therefore the example defines a `\phantomtarget`, which sets an anchor using `\hypertarget`.
- `\hyperref` with optional argument is used to replace the plain reference number by the longer phrase with name and number, both inside the link. `\ref*` with star prevents an unnecessary nested link.

Full example:

```
\documentclass[leqno]{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,allcolors=blue}
\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]

\makeatletter
\newcounter{phantomtarget}
\renewcommand*{\thephantomtarget}{phantom.\the\value{phantomtarget}}
\newcommand*{\phantomtarget}{%
  \stepcounter{phantomtarget}%
  \hypertarget{\thephantomtarget}{}%
  \edef\@currentHref{\thephantomtarget}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \phantomtarget
  \begin{theorem}
  \label{thm:a_theorem}
  \phantomtarget
    \begin{equation}
      \label{eq:an_equation}
      2 + 2 = 4
    \end{equation}
  \end{theorem}

\hyperref[eq:an_equation]{Equation (\ref*{eq:an_equation})} belongs
to \hyperref[thm:a_theorem]{Theorem \ref*{thm:a_theorem}}.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: I've posted a follow-up question to this problem [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/204146/9953). I would really appreciate if you could look at it. Thanks!