# References to begin and end of beamer allowframebreaks range

Tags: beamer, allowframebreaks

I'm using a table of contents in my beamer presentation, in which I include the first and the last slide number of each section. For this I place separate labels in the first and in the last slide, for example `\label{corpbeg}` and `\label{corpend}` and then I write

```
\begin{frame}{Table of Contents}
\begin{itemize}
\item …
\item Corpus\dotfill\ref{corpbeg}--\ref{corpend}
\item …
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

(A section always has more than one slide since it contains the section title frame and at least one slide of contents.)

The problem is that this approach does not work with the bibliography, where I'm forced to use `allowframebreaks`:

```
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{Bibliography}\label{biblbeg}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{main}
\label{biblend}
\end{frame}
```

doesn't work, I get the same number from `\ref{biblbeg}` and `\ref{biblend}` (i.e., begin and end of the bibliography), even though they are three frames apart.

How can I obtain a `\ref` towards the last slide of three-page bibliography obtained with `allowframebreaks`?

### MWE Proposal from Manuel

```
\documentclass[hyperref]{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Link Frame}
\ref{myHyperLabelBegin}--\ref{myHyperLabelEnd}    
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks, t, label=myHyperLabelBegin]
\begin{itemize}
    \item Test (First)
    \item Test
    \item Test
    \item Test
    \item Test
    \item Test
    \item Test
    \item Test
    \item Test
    \item Test
    \item Test
    \item Test
    \item Test
    \item Test
    \item Test
    \item Test
    \item Test
    \item Test
    \item Test
    \item Test
    \item Test (Last)
\end{itemize}
\label{myHyperLabelEnd}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe related **(1)** https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/204146/, **(2)** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57931209/

Comment: I added an (in my opinion) better code example. The code that you give cannot be coimpiled.

Comment: **(3)** https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/2704